# No callback with google SilentSignin api

Tags: google-signin

I am trying the sign in a user with the silent signin api. 
First time a user opens the app iam singin in the user using `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);` where the user is prompted to choose a signin email.

Next time a need a renewed token, i try to get a token in the background, by using the `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);`

code is as follows:

public void createNewToken(String serverKey, Context context) {
        this.context = context;

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(serverKey)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
        handleResult(pendingResult.get());
    } else {
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                handleResult(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, the problem is i dont get any callback, either from isDone or in the callback(). no error are given except from this:

D/GoogleSignInApiImpl: getSavedSignInResultIfEligible
 D/GoogleSignInApiImpl: trySilentSignIn

Am i dusing the api wrongly or why dosnt this work? thx for any feedback!

Comment: Should clarify that only the silentSignin arent working.

Comment: Have you tried adding ".enableAutoManage()" when building the Google API client? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: Thx steven, that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ".enableAutoManage(...)" when building the Google API client: [developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use enableAutoManage, because you are not in a FragmentActivity for example, you can call manually googleApiClient.connect() and disconnect.